# Fine Uploader w/ Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, fine-uploader

I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error trying to use  http://fineuploader.com/  with Coldfusion server side https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/tree/master/coldfusion

Console says:
[FineUploader] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (SyntaxError: Unexpected token <)  at this line in   window.console.log('<' + level + '> ' + message);

It seems its coming from the response message in the Server CFC.

```
<!--- Code provided by Pegasus Web Productions LLC - www.pegweb.com --->
<!--- get stuck use the forums http://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader --->
<!--- Tested with Adobe CF Enterprise 9.x and Fine Uploader --->
<CFCOMPONENT HINT="I do your uploads from Fine Uploader" >
<!--- function for single file submission uploads where XHR is not supported ex:->
<CFFUNCTION NAME="Upload" ACCESS="remote" OUTPUT="false" RETURNTYPE="any"     RETURNFORMAT="JSON" >
    <CFARGUMENT NAME="qqfile" TYPE="string" REQUIRED="true" />

    <CFSET var local = structNew() >
    <CFSET local.response = structNew() >
    <CFSET local.requestData = GetHttpRequestData() ><!--- get the request headers   and body --->
    <CFSET UploadDir = "/Test/file2" ><!--- set your upload directory here ex: c:\website\www\images\ --->
    <!--- check if XHR data exists --->
    <CFIF len(local.requestData.content) GT 0 >

        <CFSET local.response = UploadFileXhr(arguments.qqfile, local.requestData.content) >

        <CFELSE><!--- no XHR data so process this as standard form submission --->
            <!--- upload the file --->
            <CFFILE ACTION="upload" FILEFIELD="form.qqfile" DESTINATION="#UploadDir#" NAMECONFLICT="makeunique" >

            <!--- populate our structure with information about the image we just uploaded in case we want to use this later for CFIMAGE tags or any other processing --->
            <CFSET local.metaData = { clientFile=FILE.clientFile, clientFileExt=FILE.clientFileExt, clientFileName=FILE.clientFileName, contentSubType=FILE.contentSubType, contentType=FILE.contentType, fileSize=FILE.fileSize } />
            <!--- return the response --->
            <CFSET local.response['success'] = true >
            <CFSET local.response['type'] = 'form' >
    </CFIF>
    <CFRETURN local.response >
</CFFUNCTION>

<!--- function for browsers that support XHR ex: Almost anything but IE --->

<CFFUNCTION NAME="UploadFileXhr" ACCESS="private" OUTPUT="false" RETURNTYPE="struct" >
    <CFARGUMENT NAME="qqfile" TYPE="string" REQUIRED="true" />
    <CFARGUMENT NAME="content" TYPE="any" REQUIRED="true" />

    <CFSET var local = structNew() >
    <CFSET local.response = structNew() >
    <CFSET UploadDir = "" ><!--- set your upload directory here ex: c:\website\www\images\ --->
    <!--- write the contents of the http request to a file. The filename is passed with the qqfile variable --->
    <CFFILE ACTION="write" FILE="#UploadDir#\#arguments.qqfile#" OUTPUT="#arguments.content#" NAMECONFLICT="makeunique" >

    <!--- populate our structure with information about the image we just uploaded in case we want to use this later for CFIMAGE tags or any other processing --->
    <CFSET local.metaData = { clientFile=FILE.clientFile, clientFileExt=FILE.clientFileExt, clientFileName=FILE.clientFileName, contentSubType=FILE.contentSubType, contentType=FILE.contentType, fileSize=FILE.fileSize } />

    <!--- return custom JSON if desired--->
    <CFSET local.response['success'] = true >
    <CFSET local.response['type'] = 'xhr' >
    <CFRETURN local.response >
</CFFUNCTION>
```

Calling page

```
    <div id="thumbnail-fine-uploader">
    </div>
    <script src="/js/jQueryv1.9.1.js">
    </script>
    <script src="/Test/file2/jquery.fineuploader-3.4.1.js">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var thumbnailuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                element: $('#thumbnail-fine-uploader')[0],
                request: {
                    endpoint: 'image-uploader.cfc?method=Upload'
                },
                multiple: false,
                validation: {
                    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
                    sizeLimit: 51200 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
                },
                callbacks: {
                    onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
                        if (responseJSON.success) {
                            $('#thumbnail-fine-uploader').append('<img src="img/success.jpg" alt="' + fileName + '">');
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: The CF example was user contributed.  I'm not particularly knowledgable in CF.  The error suggests that your server-side code is not returning a valid JSON response.  It is likely returning HTML instead.  Can you paste the contents of the response, according to firebug or Chrome developer tools?

Comment: ...also, this suggests that your server is simply not parsing the request correctly and failing in the process.  Do you know where your server-side code is failing, exactly?

Comment: POST http://127.0.0.1:8500/Test/file2/image-uploader.cfc?method=Upload 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.fineuploader-3.4.1.js:3903
[FineUploader] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (SyntaxError: Unexpected token <) jquery.fineuploader-3.4.1.js:155  and I believe the cfc is failing here <!--- return custom JSON if desired--->
  <CFSET local.response['success'] = true >
  <CFSET local.response['type'] = 'xhr' >

Comment: Does this happen on all browsers?  What version of Fine Uploader are you using?  What does your client-side code look like?

Comment: Looks like I'm getting this responce qqfilechunk|IMG_2083.JPG|2679388|2000000  value
b43b6ff5-394a-4d43-a571-40b461c5a493|0|0|1041|2681470   I also added client code above

Comment: Yes 3 browsers on Mac.  Firefox, Chrome, Safari

Comment: That is simply the contents of a cookie created by Fine Uploader.  You'll need to take a closer look at your server-side code to figure out where it is failing to return a valid JSON response.  The code that returns the "success" JSON looks ok to me, so perhaps your server is failing before it reaches this line.

Comment: Got it working I was missing my upload directory path in the second method.  <CFSET UploadDir = "#expandpath('/test/file2')#" >   Thanks for the help

Comment: NP.  Please enter your result as an answer, so others with the same problem can see this easily.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working, I was missing my upload directory path in the second method.

```
<CFSET UploadDir = "#expandpath('/test/file2')#" >
```

Thanks for the help